# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to perform data input format in EPPLUS Excel upload

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, epplus

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Excel File upload using EPPLUS Excel Package.

I have this model:

```
public class LeaveApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }   
}
```

EnumList:

```
public class EnumList
{
    public enum LeaveType : byte
    {
        Annual = 1,
        Casual = 2,
        Compassionate = 3,
        Maternity = 4
    }
}
```

So I have this method for the Excel upload.

```
public async Task<List<LeaveApplication>> Import(IFormFile file)
{
    var list = new List<LeaveApplication>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
            var colcount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

            for (int row = 2; row < rowcount; row++)
            {
                list.Add(new LeaveApplication {
                    EmployeeId=worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    StartDate = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    EndDate = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    LeaveType = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().Trim()
                });
            }
        }
    }
    _dbContext.Countries.AddRange(list);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return list;
}
```

From:

```
 StartDate = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
 EndDate = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
 LeaveType = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().Trim()
```

How do I format (instead of **Value.ToString().Trim()**):

1. StartDate and EndDate Values coming from Excel to **yyyy-MM-dd**
2. LeaveType to its corresponding byte values in **enum LeaveType**

Comment: Something doesn't seem to line up in your code. Your "LeaveApplication" class doesn't have a LeaveType property.